# find an average of a column using group with inner join and then filtering through the groups

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, inner-join, having

I've been trying to solve an sqlite question where I have two tables: `Movies` and `movie_cast`.

Movies has the columns: `id`, `movie_title`, and `score. Here is a sample of the data:

- 11|Star Wars|76.496
- 62|2001:Space Odyssey|39.064
- 152|Start Trek|26.551

`movie_cast` has the columns: `movie_id`, `cast_id`, `cast_name`, `birthday`, `popularity`. Here is a sample.

- 11|2|Mark Hamill|9/25/51|15.015
- 11|3|Harrison Ford|10/21/56|8.905
- 11|5|Peter Cushing|05/26/13|6.35

IN this case `movies.id` and `movie_cast.movie_id` are the same.
The question is to Find the top ten cast members who have the highest average movie scores.
Do not include movies with score <25 in the average score calculation.
▪ Exclude cast members who have appeared in two or fewer movies.

My query is as below but it doesn't seem to get me the right answer.

```sql
SELECT movie_cast.cast_id, 
       movie_cast.cast_name, 
       printf("%.2f",CAST(AVG(movies.score) as float)), 
       COUNT(movie_cast.cast_name)
FROM movies
INNER JOIN movie_cast ON movies.id = movie_cast.movie_id
WHERE movies.score >= 25
GROUP BY movie_cast.cast_id
HAVING COUNT(movie_cast.cast_name) > 2 
ORDER BY AVG(movies.score ) DESC, movie_cast.cast_name ASC
LIMIT 10
```

The answers I get are in the format cast_id,cat_name,avg score.

-And example is: 3 Harrison Ford 52.30

I've analyzed and re-analyzed my logic but to no avail. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be great!
Thank you!

Comment: Always tag your SQL questions with `sql` and the specific DBMS (in this case `sqlite`). That way they will be seen by many more users.

Comment: Your query seems reasonable. Can you [edit] your question with some sample data and output that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: One possibility is that this requires two movies with scores of 25+, but the question doesn't have a score restriction on the number of movies.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Your query seems correct. What is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't pass the test my professors have set up for the homework. No clue why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would write the query:

```
SELECT mc.cast_id, 
       mc.cast_name, 
       PRINTF('%.2f', AVG(m.score)) avg_score
FROM movie_cast mc INNER JOIN movies m 
ON m.id = mc.movie_id
WHERE m.score >= 25
GROUP BY mc.cast_id, mc.cast_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
ORDER BY AVG(m.score) DESC, mc.cast_name ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

I use aliases for the tables to shorten the code and make it more readable.
There is no need to cast the average to a float because the average in SQLite is always a real number.
Both `COUNT(movie_cast.cast_name)` can be simplified to `COUNT(*)` but the 1st one in the `SELECT` list is not needed by your requirement (if it is then add it).
The function `PRINTF()` returns a string, but if you want a number returned then use `ROUND()`:

```
ROUND(AVG(m.score), 2) avg_score
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much! Your code gave me the exact same results my query did, but for some reason it passed the test scripts our professor wrote.